# MS infopath 2007

Tags: infopath

I have a form I have reated that I now need to have sent to multiple recipients through MS outlook.  I have no problem creating a hard coded email address and submitting the information to my database through the Submit button, however I need to be able to adjust the email addresses on the fly or give the users the option to add email recipients.  I have researched online and found that there is a built in function for this that links to the address book in outlook, however my systems admin has deactivated this feature.  So any assistance on how to perform this type of function would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going aroung the built in feature that was disabled by systems.  In the email rules I selected my database table that housed both the office name and email address in the To: & Cc: fields through the function button.  While in the function I selected my field named distro list and selected filter.  There I built a logic that states
    @Distro[@Office = @Office]
Where the first @ Office is a reference to the field in the Disro List table, and the second @ Office is from the main data connection.  This filter is basically saying return the distro list that is present in the table when the displayed main connection Office field is equal to the Distro List Office field.  Works like a champ.